# Attaching functionality to a class at build time with genericity

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a class A, which is an external class and not under my control, but i can design the specs of it.

In my code, I want to attach statically some properties and methods to A. I could inherit from A and attach the new functionality. But, since i don't know the exact specs of A, I cannot provide the constructors of A in my derived class internalA.

I could use the decorator pattern, but it seems a bit overkill since i want to decorate at build time.

Any suggestion to solve it nicely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a reference to the externalA should be sufficient.

```
template <typename A>
class InternalA {
    A &externalA;
    int property1;
    std::string property2;
    //...
public:
    InternalA (A &extA, int prop1, std::string prop2 /*...*/);
    // accessors to properties and to externalA...
};
```

But, I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: You're right, with a template to choose which class is class A. Mea culpa !

Comment: @Enjolras: Sure, I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

may be perfect forwarding and varadic templates will help:

```
#include <utility>
#include "A.h"

class B: public A
{
public:
    template<class... TT>
    B(TT&&... tt) :A(std::forward<TT>(tt)...) {}

    B(const B&)=default;
    B(B&&)=default;

    //whatever other decoration
};
```

If you prefer composition, the pattern works the same, simply A will be a member and not a base.

Comment: I didn't know default ans std::forward. It's nice, but it seems a bit complex. If i may use C++11, i could add using to inherit constructor too. But i can't.